# JSSC alternatives for getInputStream & getOutPutStream

Tags: java, serial-port, jssc

I'm trying to implement one piece of code in my application and I'm using JSSC communication library. This piece of code that I need to implement is using javax.comm.* library. The problem is in methods .getInputStream() and getOutputStream() which are not present in JSSC. Is there any alternative way in JSSC library that can replace those two methods?

Answer (score 0):

Consider these 2 source codes:
[idea 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341530/jssc-getinputstream-getoutputstream) and
[idea 2](https://github.com/allanlang/xbee-api-jssc/blob/master/src/com/rapplogic/xbee/jssc/JSSCXBeeConnection.java)
You can write your versions of these streams methods by modifying jssc.

Comment: Please consider adding key details of the links to your answer.